# How do I run this specific code 1000 times and save the results in a vector?

Tags: r, algorithm, loops

> I have the while loop here, but I am stuck in how to run this loop 1000 times and save the results as a vector x, It would be great if I could get some help!

```
n=1 
success = FALSE 
while(success == FALSE){ 
  n=n+1 #conditions
  if(rbinom(1, n, (n*n+1)^-1) == 1) 
    success = TRUE
  } 
n
```

Answer (score 1):

Write the code to repeat in a function :

```
run_function <- function(){
  n=1 
  success = FALSE
  while(!success){ 
    n=n+1
    if(rbinom(1, n, (n*n+1)^-1) == 1) 
       success = TRUE
    } 
    n
}
```

Use `replicate` to repeat it 1000 times and store the result vector in `x`.

```
x <- replicate(1000, run_function())
```